# The I-projection of a distribution to a family of distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory

For a finite set $X$, consider on $X \times X$ those distributions whose two marginals are equal. Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote the family of these distributions on $X \times X$.

I would like to determine the I-projection to $\mathcal{L}$ of $\widetilde{Q}= Q_1 \times Q_2$.

I think first I should prove that the I-projection $\widetilde{P}$ has to be of product form, $\widetilde{P} = P \times P$, so that $D(\widetilde{P}||Q_1 \times Q_2)=D(P||Q_1)+D(P||Q_2)$.

I know a theorem that states: If $Q_1, \dots, Q_n$ are arbitrary distributions over the finite sets $X_1, \dots, X_n$, and $P$ be an arbitrary distribution over $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$ with marginals $P_1, \dots, P_n$, then $$D(P||Q_1\times \cdots \times Q_n)=D(P||P_1\times \cdots \times P_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n D(P_i||Q_i).$$

Then writing the right side as one sum, I should show via the log sum inequality that its minimum is attained when $P(x)=c \sqrt{Q_1(x)Q_2(x)}$.

Unfortunately I fail at both steps.

Comment: BTW - there's been a sequence of four questions with the information theory tag that all have very similar flavour, and have all been posted by new users. Are these all by you? In that case, I'd encourage you to simply make an account! People don't mind you asking many questions here, as long as you show some effort in each one.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 O.K. Thanks. I will stick to this account from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $\mathcal{L}_P \subset \mathcal{L}$ be the family of joint distributions on $X \times X$ with marginals $P$, then from the equality you state we can notice that for any $\widetilde{P} \in \mathcal{L}_P$, $$ D( \widetilde{P}\|Q_1 \times Q_2) = D(\widetilde{P}\|P\times P) + D(P\|Q_1) + D(P\|Q_2) \\ \ge D(P\|Q_1) + D(P\|Q_2).$$

Further, $\widetilde{P} = P \times P \in \mathcal{L}_P$ and satisfies the above with equality.

Immediately, we have that the minimiser of $ D(\widetilde{P} \|Q_1 \times Q_2)$ in $\mathcal{L}_P$ must be the product distribution $P \times P$. But this is true of all $P$, and $\mathcal{L} = \bigcup_{P} \mathcal{L}_P$, and so the minimiser of $D(\widetilde{P} \|Q_1 \times Q_2)$ over $\mathcal{L}$ is also a product distribution.

That's the first part done - you'd almost got there. Let's do the second part.

We want to minimise $$ f(P) := D(P\|Q_1) + D(P\|Q_2).$$ I'll do this for discrete $X$, but the argument generalises trivially. $$ f(P) = \sum_x P(x) \log \frac{P(x)^2}{Q_1(x) Q_2(x)} = 2 \sum_x P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{Q_1(x) Q_2(x)}}$$

Define $R(x) = \frac{\sqrt{Q_1(x) Q_2(x)}}{ Z}$ where $Z = \sum_x \sqrt{Q_1(x) Q_2(x)}$. Notice that $R$ is a distribution.

We can further write $$ f(P) = 2\sum_x P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{ZR(x)} = -2\log Z + 2D(P\|R).$$

Now, the first term $-2\log Z$ in the above is a constant - it depends on $(Q_1, Q_2),$ but not on our decision variable $P$. The second term is a KL divergence, so it's non-negative. In particular it's minimised at $P = R$, and we're done.